# What are the pre-requisites/standards of integrating a chatbot application inside an angularjs web application?

Tags: angularjs, chat, chatbot

I ran into things on searching the internet :

https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/conversation/
https://conversation-demo.mybluemix.net/ (Demo)

I was really interested in below one:
http://angularjs.chat/tutorials/angularjs-basic-chat-module/

but it needs

```
You need PubNub API Keys. This gives you the Doherty Threshold speed chat communication on a data stream network.
```

Can we build a chatbot application which i can configure and handle as API and responds to the configured messages?

Like,

```
(user) Hi
(bot)> Hello

(user)ID : 12345
(bot)> Name: Gopal Kumar
  ID : 12345
  Address: Bengaluru
  Link : https://stackoverflow.com/gok
```

Or it is we need to take this chats via key generation. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can check Recast.Ai they have some good examples how to build and host chatbots using their API also I think it's free to use without much rate limitations.

Comment: Can we create any service likewise and run it independently?